# Error synchronising database while installing reviewBoard

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, mysql

Hi I am getting the following error:

```
Press Enter to continue

[!] There was an error synchronizing the database. Make sure the
    database is created and has the appropriate permissions, and then
    continue.
[!] Details: (1049, "Unknown database 'reviewboard'")

Press Enter to continue
```

to install the above db:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE reviewBoard;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> CREATE USER 'rbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysql';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'rbuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

following [this site](http://duan.pbworks.com/w/page/65088467/Install%20ReviewBoard%20on%20Ubuntu) since I am not a db guy.

Comment: First thing that sticks out is the capitalization of reviewBoard vs reviewboard. What is reviewboard?

Comment: worked that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the above error message vs. the create database statement. The problem is that you have a mismatch in the DB name. You created a DB called reviewBoard and are trying to access reviewboard - note the capital B.

You can either drop the DB and recreate it with the proper capitalization, or change your code to use the DB as created.